# About CIL and MSIL and realationship between them

Tags: .net, cil

I've strated to read an `ECMA-335` specification and I don't understand the sense yet.

**Question:**
What is the difference between `CIL` and `MSIL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like MSIL is the former name.  The new name is CIL.

> CIL was originally known as Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) during the beta releases of the .NET languages. Due to standardization of C# and the Common Language Infrastructure, the bytecode is now officially known as CIL.

From [*Common Intermediate Language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) on Wikipedia.